# How to see jquery's data() with developer tools?

Tags: html, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I am assigning data to elements with [`data()` function](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

How to see it in Chrome development tools to debug correctness?

I don't see any `data-*` attributes appearing?

---

I can see assosiated data with `Watch` if I have element object. But can I see if some data assisiated with any element in `Elements`?

Comment: You could get  the data from the  dev tools console.

Comment: jQuery's .data() doesn't use attributes, it uses an in-memory copy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [documentation for the function you are using](https://api.jquery.com/data/):

> Using the data() method to update data does not affect attributes in the DOM. To set a data-* attribute value, use attr.

If you want to read the value, you need to read it with `data()` too. jQuery won't **directly** associate it with the element. The only connection is in jQuery's internal store.