# Ajax ruins in memory data jquery element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a script that is hiding the links to mp3 files.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    
    $('a.sm2_button').each(function (i, el) {
        var data = jQuery(el).data('song_link') || jQuery(el).data('song_link', undefined);
        if (!data) {
            jQuery(el).data('song_link', el.href);
            el.href = '#'; 
            el.setAttribute('href', '#');

        }

        $(el).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        });

    });
    });
  
//--><!]]>
</script>
```

The problem that I'm having is that after an ajax call the first part of the above code gets to run again and it ruins the 'song_link' of the html that was already there before the ajax call.
When I comment out the above code, it works well, but the links are not hidden anymore. Thus I'm sure the problem is with the above code.
Apparently there is no way to debug/watch the data elements that the jquery data function is using.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65421997/how-to-see-jquerys-data-with-developer-tools

This is the html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
  <head profile="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)" />
    <title>Ajax ruins javascript  | Romanian Lesson</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style type="text/css" media="all">
@import url(".comthemes/bluemasters/css/inlineplayer.css?rmz8ol");
</style>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" media="all" />
<style type="text/css" media="all">
@import url(".comthemes/bluemasters/css/style.css?rmz8ol");
</style>

<!--[if (lte IE 8)&(!IEMobile)]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href=".comthemes/bluemasters/css/basic-layout.css?rmz8ol" media="all" />
<![endif]-->

      
      <script type="text/javascript" src=".com/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".com/misc/jquery-extend-3.4.0.js?v=1.4.4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".com/misc/jquery-html-prefilter-3.5.0-backport.js?v=1.4.4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".com/misc/jquery.once.js?v=1.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".com/misc/drupal.js?rmz8ol"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".commodules/eu_cookie_compliance/js/jquery.cookie-1.4.1.min.js?v=1.4.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".commodules/comment_notify/comment_notify.js?rmz8ol"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".comthemes/bluemasters/js/soundmanager2-nodebug-jsmin.js?rmz8ol"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".comthemes/bluemasters/js/mp3-player-button.js?rmz8ol"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".comthemes/bluemasters/js/inlineplayer.js?rmz8ol"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
soundManager.setup({  url: 'themes/bluemasters/swf/'});
//--><!]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    
    $('a.sm2_button').each(function (i, el) {
        var data = jQuery(el).data('song_link') || jQuery(el).data('song_link', undefined);
        if (!data) {
            jQuery(el).data('song_link', el.href);
        }
        el.href = '#'; 
        el.setAttribute('href', '#');

        $(el).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        });

    });
    });
  
//--><!]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // This prevents soundmanager.js from breaking links
    $('a').not('.sm2_button').each(function (i, el) {
    var data = jQuery(el).data('not_mp3') || jQuery(el).data('not_mp3', undefined);
    if (!data) {
    jQuery(el).data('not_mp3', el.href);
    }
    });
    });
//--><!]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".comthemes/bluemasters/js/jquery.mobilemenu.min.js?rmz8ol"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".commodules/captcha/captcha.js?rmz8ol"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".com/misc/textarea.js?v=7.92"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".com/modules/filter/filter.js?rmz8ol"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--

function trtables_ajax_load($nid) {
$ajax_div_target="ajax-target-start-learning-"+$nid;
$param="/node/get/ajax/"+$nid;
  jQuery("#"+$ajax_div_target).load($param);
}
//--><!]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {"basePath":"\/","pathPrefix":"","setHasJsCookie":0,"bluemasters":{"topoptiontext":"Page selection"},"ajaxPageState":{"theme":"bluemasters","theme_token":"XFjRAgiWyGJUksKw-iC68buWzLjdyMVLp-tqlrLvcuc","js":{"0":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/eu_cookie_compliance\/js\/eu_cookie_compliance.js":1,"1":1,"misc\/jquery.js":1,"misc\/jquery-extend-3.4.0.js":1,"misc\/jquery-html-prefilter-3.5.0-backport.js":1,"misc\/jquery.once.js":1,"misc\/drupal.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/eu_cookie_compliance\/js\/jquery.cookie-1.4.1.min.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/comment_notify\/comment_notify.js":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bluemasters\/js\/soundmanager2-nodebug-jsmin.js":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bluemasters\/js\/mp3-player-button.js":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bluemasters\/js\/inlineplayer.js":1,"2":1,"3":1,"4":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bluemasters\/js\/jquery.mobilemenu.min.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/captcha\/captcha.js":1,"misc\/textarea.js":1,"modules\/filter\/filter.js":1,"5":1,"6":1},"css":{"modules\/system\/system.base.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.menus.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.messages.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.theme.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/comment_notify\/comment_notify.css":1,"modules\/book\/book.css":1,"modules\/comment\/comment.css":1,"modules\/field\/theme\/field.css":1,"modules\/node\/node.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/quiz\/quiz.css":1,"modules\/search\/search.css":1,"modules\/user\/user.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bluemasters\/css\/IPA.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bluemasters\/css\/inlineplayer.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/ctools\/css\/ctools.css":1,"modules\/locale\/locale.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/adsense\/css\/adsense.css":1,"https:\/\/maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com\/font-awesome\/4.7.0\/css\/font-awesome.min.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/eu_cookie_compliance\/css\/eu_cookie_compliance.css":1,"modules\/filter\/filter.css":1,"":1,"public:\/\/ctools\/css\/85760125e0b573c174141d9adf192778.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bluemasters\/css\/960.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bluemasters\/css\/720.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bluemasters\/css\/481759.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bluemasters\/css\/mobile.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bluemasters\/css\/style.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bluemasters\/css\/basic-layout.css":1}},"eu_cookie_compliance":{"cookie_policy_version":"1.0.0","popup_enabled":1,"popup_agreed_enabled":0,"popup_hide_agreed":0,"popup_clicking_confirmation":false,"popup_scrolling_confirmation":false,"popup_html_info":"\u003Cdiv class=\u0022eu-cookie-compliance-banner eu-cookie-compliance-banner-info eu-cookie-compliance-banner--categories\u0022\u003E\n  \u003Cdiv class=\u0022popup-content info\u0022\u003E\n        \u003Cdiv id=\u0022popup-text\u0022\u003E\n      \u003Cp\u003EWe use cookies on this site to enhance your user experience\u003C\/p\u003E\n              \u003Cbutton type=\u0022button\u0022 class=\u0022find-more-button eu-cookie-compliance-more-button\u0022\u003EGive me more info\u003C\/button\u003E\n          \u003C\/div\u003E\n          \u003Cdiv id=\u0022eu-cookie-compliance-categories\u0022 class=\u0022eu-cookie-compliance-categories\u0022\u003E\n                  \u003Cdiv class=\u0022eu-cookie-compliance-category\u0022\u003E\n            \u003Cdiv\u003E\n              \u003Cinput type=\u0022checkbox\u0022 name=\u0022cookie-categories\u0022 id=\u0022cookie-category-necessary\u0022\n                     value=\u0022necessary\u0022\n                     checked                     disabled \u003E\n              \u003Clabel for=\u0022cookie-category-necessary\u0022\u003ENecessary (normal website functioning)\u003C\/label\u003E\n            \u003C\/div\u003E\n                      \u003Cdiv class=\u0022eu-cookie-compliance-category-description\u0022\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\n                  \u003C\/div\u003E\n                  \u003Cdiv class=\u0022eu-cookie-compliance-category\u0022\u003E\n            \u003Cdiv\u003E\n              \u003Cinput type=\u0022checkbox\u0022 name=\u0022cookie-categories\u0022 id=\u0022cookie-category-advertising\u0022\n                     value=\u0022advertising\u0022\n                                           \u003E\n              \u003Clabel for=\u0022cookie-category-advertising\u0022\u003EPersonalized advertisements\u003C\/label\u003E\n            \u003C\/div\u003E\n                      \u003Cdiv class=\u0022eu-cookie-compliance-category-description\u0022\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\n                  \u003C\/div\u003E\n                          \u003Cdiv class=\u0022eu-cookie-compliance-categories-buttons\u0022\u003E\n            \u003Cbutton type=\u0022button\u0022\n                    class=\u0022eu-cookie-compliance-save-preferences-button\u0022\u003ESave preferences\u003C\/button\u003E\n          \u003C\/div\u003E\n              \u003C\/div\u003E\n    \n    \u003Cdiv id=\u0022popup-buttons\u0022 class=\u0022eu-cookie-compliance-has-categories\u0022\u003E\n            \u003Cbutton type=\u0022button\u0022 class=\u0022agree-button eu-cookie-compliance-default-button\u0022\u003EAccept all cookies\u003C\/button\u003E\n          \u003C\/div\u003E\n  \u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003E","use_mobile_message":false,"mobile_popup_html_info":"\u003Cdiv class=\u0022eu-cookie-compliance-banner eu-cookie-compliance-banner-info eu-cookie-compliance-banner--categories\u0022\u003E\n  \u003Cdiv class=\u0022popup-content info\u0022\u003E\n        \u003Cdiv id=\u0022popup-text\u0022\u003E\n                    \u003Cbutton type=\u0022button\u0022 class=\u0022find-more-button eu-cookie-compliance-more-button\u0022\u003EGive me more info\u003C\/button\u003E\n          \u003C\/div\u003E\n          \u003Cdiv id=\u0022eu-cookie-compliance-categories\u0022 class=\u0022eu-cookie-compliance-categories\u0022\u003E\n                  \u003Cdiv class=\u0022eu-cookie-compliance-category\u0022\u003E\n            \u003Cdiv\u003E\n              \u003Cinput type=\u0022checkbox\u0022 name=\u0022cookie-categories\u0022 id=\u0022cookie-category-necessary\u0022\n                     value=\u0022necessary\u0022\n                     checked                     disabled \u003E\n              \u003Clabel for=\u0022cookie-category-necessary\u0022\u003ENecessary (normal website functioning)\u003C\/label\u003E\n            \u003C\/div\u003E\n                      \u003Cdiv class=\u0022eu-cookie-compliance-category-description\u0022\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\n                  \u003C\/div\u003E\n                  \u003Cdiv class=\u0022eu-cookie-compliance-category\u0022\u003E\n            \u003Cdiv\u003E\n              \u003Cinput type=\u0022checkbox\u0022 name=\u0022cookie-categories\u0022 id=\u0022cookie-category-advertising\u0022\n                     value=\u0022advertising\u0022\n                                           \u003E\n              \u003Clabel for=\u0022cookie-category-advertising\u0022\u003EPersonalized advertisements\u003C\/label\u003E\n            \u003C\/div\u003E\n                      \u003Cdiv class=\u0022eu-cookie-compliance-category-description\u0022\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\n                  \u003C\/div\u003E\n                          \u003Cdiv class=\u0022eu-cookie-compliance-categories-buttons\u0022\u003E\n            \u003Cbutton type=\u0022button\u0022\n                    class=\u0022eu-cookie-compliance-save-preferences-button\u0022\u003ESave preferences\u003C\/button\u003E\n          \u003C\/div\u003E\n              \u003C\/div\u003E\n    \n    \u003Cdiv id=\u0022popup-buttons\u0022 class=\u0022eu-cookie-compliance-has-categories\u0022\u003E\n            \u003Cbutton type=\u0022button\u0022 class=\u0022agree-button eu-cookie-compliance-default-button\u0022\u003EAccept all cookies\u003C\/button\u003E\n          \u003C\/div\u003E\n  \u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003E\n","mobile_breakpoint":"768","popup_html_agreed":"\u003Cdiv\u003E\n  \u003Cdiv class=\u0022popup-content agreed\u0022\u003E\n    \u003Cdiv id=\u0022popup-text\u0022\u003E\n      \u003Cp\u003EThank you for accepting cookiesYou can now hide this message or find out more about cookies.\u003C\/p\u003E\n    \u003C\/div\u003E\n    \u003Cdiv id=\u0022popup-buttons\u0022\u003E\n      \u003Cbutton type=\u0022button\u0022 class=\u0022hide-popup-button eu-cookie-compliance-hide-button\u0022\u003EHide\u003C\/button\u003E\n              \u003Cbutton type=\u0022button\u0022 class=\u0022find-more-button eu-cookie-compliance-more-button-thank-you\u0022 \u003EMore info\u003C\/button\u003E\n          \u003C\/div\u003E\n  \u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003E","popup_use_bare_css":false,"popup_height":"auto","popup_width":"100%","popup_delay":1000,"popup_link":"\/privacy","popup_link_new_window":1,"popup_position":null,"fixed_top_position":false,"popup_language":"en","store_consent":true,"better_support_for_screen_readers":0,"reload_page":0,"domain":"","domain_all_sites":0,"popup_eu_only_js":1,"cookie_lifetime":"100","cookie_session":false,"disagree_do_not_show_popup":0,"method":"categories","allowed_cookies":"","withdraw_markup":"\u003Cbutton type=\u0022button\u0022 class=\u0022eu-cookie-withdraw-tab\u0022\u003E\u003C\/button\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022eu-cookie-withdraw-banner\u0022\u003E\n  \u003Cdiv class=\u0022popup-content info\u0022\u003E\n    \u003Cdiv id=\u0022popup-text\u0022\u003E\n          \u003C\/div\u003E\n    \u003Cdiv id=\u0022popup-buttons\u0022\u003E\n      \u003Cbutton type=\u0022button\u0022 class=\u0022eu-cookie-withdraw-button\u0022\u003E\u003C\/button\u003E\n    \u003C\/div\u003E\n  \u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003E\n","withdraw_enabled":false,"withdraw_button_on_info_popup":0,"cookie_categories":["necessary","advertising"],"cookie_categories_details":{"necessary":{"weight":0,"machine_name":"necessary","label":"Necessary (normal website functioning)","description":"","checkbox_default_state":"required"},"advertising":{"weight":0,"machine_name":"advertising","label":"Personalized advertisements","description":"","checkbox_default_state":"unchecked"}},"enable_save_preferences_button":1,"cookie_name":"","cookie_value_disagreed":"0","cookie_value_agreed_show_thank_you":"1","cookie_value_agreed":"2","containing_element":"body","automatic_cookies_removal":1,"close_button_action":"close_banner"},"wysiwyg":{"triggers":{"edit-comment-body-und-0-value":{"field":"edit-comment-body-und-0-value","resizable":1,"activeFormat":"plain_text"}}},"urlIsAjaxTrusted":{"\/comment\/reply\/5801":true}});
//--><!]]>
</script>
  </head>
  <body class="html not-front not-logged-in no-sidebars page-node page-node- page-node-5801 node-type-book i18n-en" >
        <div id="page">
  
          

        </div>
    </div>
    <!--EOF:header-top-->

    <div id="wrapper">

        
        <div class="container_12">
            <div class="grid_12">
                <div id="main-area" class="clearfix">
                
                    <div id="main-area-inside" class="clearfix">
                                                                                <div class="grid_12 alpha omega">    
                        
                            <div id="main"  class="inside clearfix">

                                                           
                                                         
                                                                
                                                                
                                
                                                   
                                  <div class="region region-content">
    <div id="block-system-main" class="block block-system">


<div class="content">

<div id="node-5801" class="node node-book" about="/node/5801" typeof="sioc:Item foaf:Document">

 
  <div class="content clearfix">
    <div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded"><table class="mp3table">
                                <tr>
                                <th>English</th>
                                <th>Romanian<br>translation</th>
                                <th>Audio</th>
                                </tr><tr class='odd'><td><p>I&#39;m not Romanian (male)</p></td><td><p>Eu nu sunt român</p></td><td><A class="sm2_button no_dl" href="/sites/default/files/Lessons/0.4/eu_nu_sunt_roman.mp3"></A></td></tr><tr class='even'><td><p>I&#39;m not Romanian (female)</p></td><td><p>Eu nu sunt româncă</p></td><td><A class="sm2_button no_dl" href="/sites/default/files/Lessons/0.4/eu_nu_sunt_romanca.mp3"></A></td></tr></table>    <a id="id-start-learning-611"></a>
    <div class="learning-panel">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-blue" type="button" style="color: yellow; width: 100%;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#start-learning-611" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="start-learning-611">
          <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <img style="margin:10px 0px;padding:0px;" width="30px"    height="30px" title="Multiple choice Romanian language exercises"src=themes/bluemasters/images/icons/mcq.png>&nbsp;<img style="margin:10px 0px;padding:0px;" width="30px"   height="30px" title="Multiple choice Romanian language listening exercises" src=themes/bluemasters/images/icons/listen.png>&nbsp;<img style="margin:10px 0px;padding:0px;" width="30px" height="30px" title="Listening and writing Romanian language exercises" src=themes/bluemasters/images/icons/w_h.jpg>&nbsp;Start learning&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         </button>
      <div class="in collapse show" id="start-learning-611">
        <div class="container-fluid center">
          <div class="row btn-blue">
            <div class="level1 col"><div class="blue vertically-center-text"><a class="btn" href="#id-start-learning-611" onclick="trtables_ajax_load('611,')">1 <img style="margin:10px 0px;padding:0px;" width="30px" height="30px" title="Multiple choice Romanian language exercises"src=themes/bluemasters/images/icons/mcq.png></a> <span class="lro-progress">0/2</span></div></div>
            
            <div class="level1 col">2 Listening
              <div class="row" style="margin: 7px;">
                <div class="col line-height50 no-border-right blue"><div class="vertically-center-text"><a class="btn" href="#id-start-learning-611" onclick="trtables_ajax_load('611,p')">2.1 <img style="margin:10px 0px;padding:0px;" width="30px"   height="30px" title="Multiple choice Romanian language listening exercises" src=themes/bluemasters/images/icons/listen.png></a> <span class="lro-progress">0/2</span></div></div>
                <div class="col line-height50 blue"><a class="btn" href="#id-start-learning-611" onclick="trtables_ajax_load('611,tp')">2.2 <img style="margin:10px 0px;padding:0px;" width="30px"  height="30px" title="Listening and writing Romanian language exercises" src=themes/bluemasters/images/icons/w_h.jpg></a> <span class="lro-progress">0/2</span></div>
              </div>
            </div><!-- /.level1 -->
            <div class="level1 col">
              3 Translate
              <div class="row" style="margin: 7px;">
                <div class="col line-height50 no-border-right blue"><a class="btn" href="#id-start-learning-611" onclick="trtables_ajax_load('611,trofl')">3.1 <img class="language-icon" typeof="foaf:Image" src="modules/languageicons/flags/ro.png" style="margin:0px;width:26px;height:20px;max-width:100px;"> <img class="language-icon" typeof="foaf:Image" src=modules/languageicons/flags/en.png style="margin:0px;width:26px;height:20px;max-width:100px;"></a> <span class="lro-progress">0/2</span></div>
                <div class="col line-height50 blue"><a class="btn" href="#id-start-learning-611" onclick="trtables_ajax_load('611,tflro')">3.2 <img class="language-icon" typeof="foaf:Image" src=modules/languageicons/flags/en.png style="margin:0px;width:26px;height:20px;max-width:100px;"> <img class="language-icon" typeof="foaf:Image" src="modules/languageicons/flags/ro.png" style="margin:0px;width:26px;height:20px;max-width:100px;"></a> <span class="lro-progress">0/2</span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ajax-target-start-learning-611"></div></p>
</div></div></div>  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

The html page that the ajax is brining thus this is the ajax reply is:

```
<html><head><title></title>
<style type="text/css" media="all">
@import url(".comthemes/bluemasters/css/inlineplayer.css?rmz8ol");
@import url(".commodules/ctools/css/ctools.css?rmz8ol");
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="all">
@import url(".comthemes/bluemasters/css/style.css?rmz8ol");
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".com/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".com/misc/jquery-extend-3.4.0.js?v=1.4.4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".com/misc/jquery-html-prefilter-3.5.0-backport.js?v=1.4.4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".com/misc/jquery.once.js?v=1.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".com/misc/drupal.js?rmz8ol"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".commodules/eu_cookie_compliance/js/jquery.cookie-1.4.1.min.js?v=1.4.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".com/misc/jquery.form.js?v=2.52"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".com/misc/ajax.js?v=7.92"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".commodules/jquery_update/js/jquery_update.js?v=0.0.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".commodules/comment_notify/comment_notify.js?rmz8ol"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".comthemes/bluemasters/js/soundmanager2-nodebug-jsmin.js?rmz8ol"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".comthemes/bluemasters/js/mp3-player-button.js?rmz8ol"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".comthemes/bluemasters/js/inlineplayer.js?rmz8ol"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
soundManager.setup({  url: 'themes/bluemasters/swf/'});
//--><!]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    
    $('a.sm2_button').each(function (i, el) {
        var data = jQuery(el).data('song_link') || jQuery(el).data('song_link', undefined);
        if (!data) {
            jQuery(el).data('song_link', el.href);
        }
        el.href = '#'; 
        el.setAttribute('href', '#');

        $(el).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        });

    });
    });
  
//--><!]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // This prevents soundmanager.js from breaking links
    $('a').not('.sm2_button').each(function (i, el) {
    var data = jQuery(el).data('not_mp3') || jQuery(el).data('not_mp3', undefined);
    if (!data) {
    jQuery(el).data('not_mp3', el.href);
    }
    });
    });
//--><!]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".comthemes/bluemasters/js/jquery.mobilemenu.min.js?rmz8ol"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".commodules/trtable_quiz/trtable_quiz.js?rmz8ol"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".com/misc/progress.js?v=7.92"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {"basePath":"\/","pathPrefix":"","setHasJsCookie":0,"bluemasters":{"topoptiontext":"Page selection"},"ajaxPageState":{"theme":"bluemasters","theme_token":"XFjRAgiWyGJUksKw-iC68buWzLjdyMVLp-tqlrLvcuc","jquery_version":"default","css":{"modules\/system\/system.base.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.menus.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.messages.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.theme.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/comment_notify\/comment_notify.css":1,"modules\/book\/book.css":1,"modules\/comment\/comment.css":1,"modules\/field\/theme\/field.css":1,"modules\/node\/node.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/quiz\/quiz.css":1,"modules\/search\/search.css":1,"modules\/user\/user.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bluemasters\/css\/IPA.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bluemasters\/css\/inlineplayer.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/ctools\/css\/ctools.css":1,"":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bluemasters\/css\/960.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bluemasters\/css\/720.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bluemasters\/css\/481759.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bluemasters\/css\/mobile.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bluemasters\/css\/style.css":1},"js":{"misc\/jquery.js":1,"misc\/jquery-extend-3.4.0.js":1,"misc\/jquery-html-prefilter-3.5.0-backport.js":1,"misc\/jquery.once.js":1,"misc\/drupal.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/eu_cookie_compliance\/js\/jquery.cookie-1.4.1.min.js":1,"misc\/jquery.form.js":1,"misc\/ajax.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/jquery_update\/js\/jquery_update.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/comment_notify\/comment_notify.js":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bluemasters\/js\/soundmanager2-nodebug-jsmin.js":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bluemasters\/js\/mp3-player-button.js":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bluemasters\/js\/inlineplayer.js":1,"0":1,"1":1,"2":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bluemasters\/js\/jquery.mobilemenu.min.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/trtable_quiz\/trtable_quiz.js":1,"misc\/progress.js":1}},"ajax":{"edit-check":{"wrapper":"trtable_quiz_multistep_form882","callback":"trtable_quiz_multistep_form_ajax_callback","effect":"fade","event":"click","url":"\/system\/ajax","submit":{"_triggering_element_name":"op","_triggering_element_value":"Check"}}},"urlIsAjaxTrusted":{"\/system\/ajax":true,"\/node\/get\/ajax\/611,":true}});
//--><!]]>
</script>
</head><body class="jquery-ajax-load"><form action="/node/get/ajax/611," method="post" id="trtable-quiz-multistep-form" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-gJCwC0aoS9T_Hj_ubOnVTLK8dCyToMvSbKFkXfyw5NU" />
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="trtable_quiz_multistep_form" />
<input type="hidden" name="honeypot_time" value="1671191916|IzeBmhlVRv-taaRUWd2p-bFWOUfiMoTEJO12hb_xz_I" />
<div id="trtable_quiz_multistep_form882"><div class="trtable-quiz form-wrapper" id="edit-quiz"><p>Question 1 / 2</p><h4>What is the correct translation for:</h4><em style="color:blue;"><p>I&#39;m not Romanian (female)</p></em><ul class="exercise_ul"><div id="edit-question-0" class="form-radios"><div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-question-0">
 <input placeholder="" onBlur="lasttext=this;" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13){event.preventDefault();document.querySelector(&quot;#trtable_quiz_multistep_form882 input.trtable-quiz-forward-button&quot;).click();}" lang="ro" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" type="radio" id="edit-question-0-1" name="question_0" value="1" class="form-radio" />  <label class="option" for="edit-question-0-1"><a class="sm2_link no_dl" href="/sites/default/files/Lessons/0.4/eu_nu_sunt_romanca.mp3">Eu nu sunt româncă</a> </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-question-0">
 <input placeholder="" onBlur="lasttext=this;" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13){event.preventDefault();document.querySelector(&quot;#trtable_quiz_multistep_form882 input.trtable-quiz-forward-button&quot;).click();}" lang="ro" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" type="radio" id="edit-question-0-0" name="question_0" value="0" class="form-radio" />  <label class="option" for="edit-question-0-0"><a class="sm2_link no_dl" href="/sites/default/files/Lessons/0.4/eu_nu_sunt_roman.mp3">Eu nu sunt român</a> </label>

</div>
</div></ul><div id="quiz-message882"></div><div id="edit-buttons" class="form-wrapper"><input class="next_button next_button1 trtable-quiz-forward-button form-submit" style="display: none" type="submit" id="edit-check" name="op" value="Check" /></div></div></div><div class="url-textfield"><div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-url">
  <label for="edit-url">Leave this field blank </label>
 <input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="edit-url" name="url" value="" size="20" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
</div>
</div></div></form></body></html>
```

How can I prevent the second run triggered by ajax from ruining the 'song_link' jquery data element?

The same code needs to be fin for both the first run, when the page loads, which is working now and for the second run when the ajax is triggered.
P.S. In case it's easier: My test site is here: http://test2.learnro.com/node/5801

Comment: You are doing `el.href = '#';` after you set the `song_link` data item - so just _don't_ set `song_link`, if the element's href is _already_ `#` ...?

Comment: Well the ```el.href= "#';``` is set only ```!data``` thus it should not be called on a second run. And anyway the problem is the content of the song_link that "disappears" after the second ajax run. I need to leave the ```el.href= "#';``` for the first run to set the href to "#". This is the purpose of the script to hide the href.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you are trying to say there. And instead of the code for the player, you should give us a proper example of what HTL this is operating on, and what exactly it is you are loading with your AJAX request.

Comment: I added the original html and the ajax html reply. I had to remove some unimportant html tags as I could not post more than 30000 characters. I'm happy to hear your views on the above

Comment: And where is the AJAX code that loads this and inserts it into the current document? Right now there is no way to tell whether this replaces the already existing elements, or only appends the new ones.

Comment: The call to the ajax function is : trtables_ajax_load, it is triggered on the buttons in html one of them being: ```<a class="btn" href="#id-start-learning-611" onclick="trtables_ajax_load('611,')"><strong>1</strong> <img style="margin:10px 0px;padding:0px;" width="30px" height="30px" title="Multiple choice Romanian language exercises" src="/sites/all/themes/bluemasters/images/icons/mcq.png"></a>```

Comment: So you are sticking a _full_ HTML document, that includes doctype, html, head and body elements, _into_ an element in your current page. That is the first thing you should fix here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I fully agree. However this comes with druapl. I spent almost 2 hours to add only the html code that I need and then to add the right javascripts that I need for that multistep form to work, and could not make it. I am working on it, but it might be very complicated to reconstruct manually something that is made automatically by a framework. As I was saying above, I narrowed it down to the script that I highlighted in my initial post on top. Thus if I disable that script it works.

Comment: Without delving into your code, it looks/sounds like you have element "A" that has data attributes - you then *replace* element "A" with another element ("B") that has the same HTML, but *is not the same instance*, so does not have the same data attributes.  You might need to store whatever it is you need to store in a variable in javascript (eg an array/dictionary) rather than rely on data- attributes/jquery's data store.

Comment: The ajax call, does not replace element "A" it adds other elements "B". It just adds it with a full html including all the javascript that comes with it, including the problematic one ``` $('a.sm2_button').each(function (i, el)``` that is run a second time since it's a script that is run on all pages, thus it is also triggered when the ajax call brings a new page. I do not understand

Comment: In summary: when you get a "page" with ajax, don't get a full page - only get what you need.  Try to limit it to HTML.  Load all the javascript you do or might need in the first load (excluding any data that you're loading into js eg via json).

Answer (score 0):

First of all thank you very much for your constructive answers. Following your feedback I found the following solution:

```
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    
    $('a.sm2_button').each(function (i, el) {
        var data = jQuery(el).data('song_link') || jQuery(el).data('song_link', undefined);
        if (!el.song_link) {
            el.song_link=el.href;
            el.href = '#'; 
            el.setAttribute('href', '#');
        }

        $(el).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        });

    });
    });
  
//--><!]]>
</script>
```

I have adapted the other scripts as well, that are used to play the mp3s.

Thus I basically replaced the jQuery data function with an new attribute to el.

One more time many thanks!